# basic undefined method for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups:::0x00000101906440>

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, undefined, fizzbuzz

I started and to code back in 2013 and took a break from it and decided to start from scratch. But for the life of me cannot get pass this error. I've done everything I can think of, but it's not requiring the methods from the lib file.

here is my folder structure

```
fizzbuzz
  lib/
    fizzbuzz.rb
spec/
  fizzbuzz_spec.rb
  spec_helper.rb
.rspec
```

fizzbuzz_spec.rb file

```
require "fizzbuzz"

describe "fizzbuzz" do 

  it "tells me that 3 is divisible by 3" do 
    expect(divisible_by_three?(3)).to_eq true
  end

end
```

Heres the fizzbuzz.rb file

```
def fizzbuzz

  def divisible_by_three? (number)
    number % 3 ==0
  end

end
```

Yes I understand it's not the most puzzling thing in the world. But my mind s a blank and I've troubledshoot this and searched online and followed tutorials to do it another way, but it never seems to call the method.

I've used

```
require "fizzbuzz" 
require './lib/fizzbuzz' 
require_relative '../lib/fizzbuzz'
```

Please help, please and thank yous.

Kind regards,

Grateful developer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here as I see it.  In the `lib/fizzbuzz.rb` file, your method `divisible_by_three?` method is enclosed in another method.  While this is technically allowed, it's not really advisable if it can be avoided.  Instead, change `def fizzbuzz` to `class Fizzbuzz`.

```
class Fizzbuzz

  def divisible_by_three? (number)
    number % 3 ==0
  end

end
```

In the spec file, `require_relative '../lib/fizzbuzz'` is fine.  However, to use the method (at least as defined in the previous snippet), you'll need to use an instance of the class to have access to the method.  See the snippet below.

```
require_relative '../lib/fizzbuzz'

describe "fizzbuzz" do
  let(:instance) { Fizzbuzz.new }
  it "tells me that 3 is divisible by 3" do
    expect(instance.divisible_by_three?(3)).to eq true
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to finish the whole  thing straight after. I hadn't realised I needed a instance and that I didn't correctly make a class.